# jQuery TimeAgo plugin - Set Settings

Tags: jquery, plugins, timeago

I'm trying to "tweek" the TimeAgo plugin so that I can remove the suffix "ago" on a case by case basis.

Here's what I've tried

```
$("time.timeago-nosuffix").timeago({suffixAgo: ""});
```

and

```
$("time.timeago-nosuffix").timeago({ settings: { strings: { suffixAgo: null}} });
```

as well as

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("time.timeago").timeago();
    $("time.timeago-nosuffix").timeago(function () {
        suffixAgo: "" 
    });
});
```

with out any luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just set `suffixAgo` to a blank string

```
$("time.timeago-nosuffix").timeago({strings: {suffixAgo: ""}});
```

**UPDATE** 
Looks like the current version of the plugin doesn't handle runtime options.  I created a fork of the git repository and created a version that does:

https://github.com/petersendidit/jquery-timeago/blob/master/jquery.timeago.js

Comment: because of your answer, I decided to change my approach, so I've edited my question.

Comment: Looks like the timeago plugin only has global settings and not per element settings.  Looking in to adding per element settings.

Comment: oh, cool.  Yeah my JS chops aren't nearly good enough to modify that.

Comment: Looks like there is a ticket to add this type of option: https://github.com/rmm5t/jquery-timeago/issues#issue/3

Comment: ah yes, too bad there's been no activity since January 2010.

Comment: Just created a fork of the git repository and created a version that handles runtime options: https://github.com/petersendidit/jquery-timeago/blob/master/jquery.timeago.js

Comment: Nice!! I'm just on a dinner break. I'll check it out when i get back.

Comment: I've tested it out.  I replaced my version of timeago with the one you uploaded on github, and then I used this in my view `$("time.timeago-nosuffix").timeago({ suffixAgo: null });` The result is still **5 minutes ago**

Comment: Try `$("time.timeago-nosuffix").timeago({strings: {suffixAgo: ""}});`

Answer (score 7):

*Disclaimer: I'm the author of timeago.*

Unfortunately, as PetersenDidIt pointed out, timeago doesn't currently support runtime options.  There's been an open issue on GitHub to address this, but I haven't had the time to look into it.  PetersenDidIt, Thanks for the pull-request.  I'll take a look as soon as I can.

**Meanwhile, here's one of several possible workarounds...**

First, set the suffix to an empty string by default:

```
$.timeago.settings.strings.suffixAgo = "";
```

Next, run timeago like you normally would:

```
$("time.timeago").timeago()
```

Lastly, instead of adding a "nosuffix" qualifier, add a class to each timestamp for which you want a suffix and add the suffix to all of those timestamps once:

```
$("time.timeago.suffix").after(" ago")
```

Comment: Thanks Ryan for chiming in.  I have tested @PetersenDidIt's solution and it seems to be knocking it out of the park.  I absolutely love your plugin and I think it's superior to the other ones out there!!! Kudos.